# One customer with multiple customer groups Magento 2

Tags: customer, magento2.2, customer-group

Does anyone know how to apply multiple groups for one single customer?

I have seen one result for Magento 1.8 but it doesn't work.
 I have changed the DB to multiselect and not static value (varchar) on group_id, but in the admin panel the changes are not being saved.

Any idea?

Comment: I have same problem. did you find solution?

Comment: I have done this functionality for one customer with multiple customer groups. if anyone needs then add a comment I will post Answers.

Comment: @ViralPatel I would love to see your solution. Please post it.